# Help with pwgen syntax

Tags: security, password

This is what I'm working with:

> pwgen 15 1 -cny

I need to include at least one uppercase letter, one number and one symbol.

What I need to change is to make it include one of these symbols:

> "! @ # $ % ^ * - _ + = & ~"

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-r` to specify list of characters to not be included in the password, so if you want only specific list of symbols to be used, you can use [list of symbols pwgen uses](https://github.com/tytso/pwgen/blob/master/pw_rand.c#L19), remove yours from the list and use it for `-r`.

```
pwgen 15 1 -cny -r "\"\'(),./:;<>?[\\]\`{|}"
T+aPpfP61Y6yZs!
```

Unfortunately this will stop working if `pwgen` ever decides to change the list of symbols but I don't see other way to do it with `pwgen` only.